# cannot setup Opencv 2.4.6 , opencv_core231d.lib Not Found Error

Tags: opencv

**Hello everyone;**

i had opencv 2.2 on my vs2010, and i wanted to update so i went to opencv site and:

1. i've downloaded OpenCV for Windows (ver 2.4.6)
2. i've extracted it to c:\opencv2.4
3. i've set the Environment Variable  as doc said here: http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/introduction/windows_install/windows_install.html#windowssetpathandenviromentvariable
   ( i didnt know what is "PATH EDITOR" so i've just changed Environment variables)
4. i made property sprite sheets as opencv doc said here: http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/introduction/windows_visual_studio_Opencv/windows_visual_studio_Opencv.html#windows-visual-studio-how-to
   5.but Doc Was Old, and there was no "include" folder in OpenCV2.4/opencv/build/x64/vc10 so I did set include Directory to OpenCV2.4/opencv/build/include in My property sprite sheet.
5. everything seems true and VS detect include libraries But 
   VS2010 throw following error when i want to Build the solution:
   1>LINK : fatal error LNK1104: cannot open file 'opencv_core231d.lib'

Strange thing is there is no "opencv_core231d.lib" File in c:\opencv2.4 at all!!!

:(

what is the problem?

Comment: Maybe you should include opencv_core246d.lib?

Comment: OH Ofcourse! Doc is Old and there is no such library in opencv.2.4.6 any more!
Thanks bkausbk :)

Comment: use dependency walker and fix ur missing lib or dlls from here http://www.dependencywalker.com/

Answer (score 0):

This is a Linker error, so make sure you are trying to link the correct libraries.
I would suggest to use CMake, which definitely simplifies configuring projects, specially those having dependencies like OpenCV (you can take a look to the OpenCV documentation, or any blog explaining the steps: http://marcosnietoblog.wordpress.com/2011/11/19/opencv-for-windows-easy-installation-using-cmake/ )

By the way, I use to have several versions of opencv on the same folder:

```
C:\OpenCV\opencv2.4.3    
C:\OpenCV\opencv2.4.6
```

...
So I can easily switch within CMake setting the OpenCV_DIR.

Answer (score 0):

`opencv_core231d.lib` is a debug version, all the ***d.lib** and ***d.dll** files in openCV are with debug symbols.

It is likely that the pre-built release you downloaded doesn't contain debug ones.
either download te source and build both debug and release. Or, if you don't care how opencv works internally, just change the linker flags to use the same lib names with the **d**

edit. or of course if you donwloaded opencv 2.4.6 the file would be `opencv_core246d.lib`